# Create vector with one column records having max values of remaining columns

Tags: r

I am fresher to R language, and working around some Q/A's, being stuck at the question where I have to find Food vector having max energy, max water and max fiber, please help me how can I do the best possible way?
Table as below:

```
Food      energy    water   fiber  
Apple     207       84      2.3  
Apricot   153       87      2.1  
Avocado   523       81      0.2  
Blueberry 204       80      8.4  
Blackberry170       85      8.7
```

Comment: What is your desired output? You want to find a maximum in each column and then subset it each time? E.g., something like `df[,1][sapply(df[-1], which.max)]` ? (if `df` is your dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

To get the row with the maximum value in a column, where df is your above dataframe try:

```
maxEnergy <- df[which.max(df$energy),]
maxWater <- df[which.max(df$water),]
maxFiber <- df[which.max(df$fiber),]
```